# sending an email in unix and linux shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am completely new to Linux, unix shell scripting I am into new role  as support analyst on shell scripting. To introduce my self I am IT background but never worked with shell scripting. I have an idea and knowledge of basic commands but not in depth knowledge. I have a task today.

To send an email from terminal we need to install mailutils package first?

To alter the loop where the script detects the glassfish process is still running and send out an email after 10 attempts. code below

```
while [[ $glassfishPid -gt 0 ]];

do

 echo "Glassfish is running.  Killing Glassfish process..." $GlassfishPid

 kill -9 $GlassfishPid

 echo "Process killed" $GlassfishPid `date`

 GlassfishPid=`ps -ef|grep  "glassfish.jar" |grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'`

 done

echo Glassfish shutdown at `date`.
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "hello" | sendmail -f from@gmail.com -t to@yahoo.` It should send Hello. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Mr_pzling_Pie , Do we need to edit/add anything into that loop?

Comment: you should not have to. Sorry, I was on vacation.